# How to pass an array to a function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how to check whether the key value is in the array `x()`? But it just pops up the Compile error:

> Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

````vb
    Public Function Find(ByRef x() As Integer, _
                        ByVal key As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim low1 As Integer
    Dim high1 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    'Dim low2 As Integer
    'Dim high2 As Integer
    low1 = LBound(x)
    high1 = UBound(x)
    
        For i = low1 To high1
            'For j = low2 To high2
            If x(i) = key Then
                Find = "Found"
            End If
                
    End Function
    
    ```
    Sub test1()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x() As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Variant
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    a = Range("A1", [a1].End(xlDown)).count
    ReDim x(a) As Integer
        For i = 1 To a
            x(i) = Range("A" & CStr(i))
        Next
    count = 1
    For Each j In x
        Worksheets(1).Cells(count, "B") = Find(j, 18)
        count = count + 1
    Next
    
            
    End Sub
````

[image: error dialog]

Hope that someone can tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Worksheets(1).Cells(count, "B") = Find(x, 18)  'Find arguments are a reference to an Array and Integer.

Comment: The function returns a boolean but you are trying to assign it a string with `Find = "Found"`. Also `ReDim x(a) As Integer` will create an array with one more elements than the value of `a` because `Ubound(x) = a` but `Lbound(x) = 0`

Comment: Typed arrays are a mess in VBA, just use a `Variant` instead.

Answer (score 0):

CDP1802 is correct in saying you're trying to return a string-type variable when you have explicitly stated it must return a Boolean.

That being said, I'll go ahead and share a function from utilities I've created for this type of problem:

```
Public Function InArray(theValue As Variant, theArray) As Boolean
'________________________________________________________________________________________________
' Purpose:
'   -> to assess if a value is in an array
'________________________________________________________________________________________________
' Parameters:
'   - theValue, any type
'   -----> the value to search for in the array
'   - theArray, Array
'   -----> The array to search for the value in
'________________________________________________________________________________________________
' Returns:
'   - Boolean
'   -----> Boolean is True if value is in array, False if not
'________________________________________________________________________________________________
On Error GoTo Err
    Dim iter As Long
    For iter = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)
        If theArray(iter) = theValue Then
            InArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iter
    InArray = False
    Exit Function
Err:
    ' on error, tell the user the error and stop the code for debugging
    Call MsgBox("An error occurred in the Public Function InArray. The code will stop:" _
                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical)
    Stop
End Function
```